# IOS keeps connecting to neighbors weak wifi

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

I have my neighbors wifi and use it regularly when I'm on the part of my property that is closer to their home.

Whenever I arrive home, I pass by their house first so my iPhone connects to their wifi first, and then never updates to mine even when the signal of theirs is completely useless.  Further, my iPhone will randomly re-connect to their wifi.

I read somewhere that IOS will prioritize a network that you actively select, and de-prioritize one that you actively select against but this has proven false.  I've tried searching for an app to manage this for me, but none could be found.

**How do I make my phone connect to the very strong signal in my home rather than the very weak one 200 yards away?**

Comment: Do you also have a Mac?

Comment: One option is to turn off **Auto-join** for the neighbor's WiFi and do a manual connect when needed (yes, I did see that you use it regularly but this may be a temp solution).